# Get title of YouTube video

Tags: android, youtube

What is the easiest way to get the title of a single YouTube video in Android? I'm using the Android YouTube API to play video's but they don't return a title cause it only supports playback options. The only thing I need is to display the title of the video, I obviously have the video ID itself but I don't have a clue where to start.

Things I looked at:

- YouTube Data API
- JSOUP(I can see the tag but don't know how to get it)

For some reason I find it hard to understand how to use them and this seems like a really simple action to me. I'm curious if there is an easier option or if there is someone who can help me get on the right track with this.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use this code for this purpose.

```
public class SimpleYouTubeHelper {

public static String getTitleQuietly(String youtubeUrl) {
    try {
        if (youtubeUrl != null) {
            URL embededURL = new URL("http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=" +
                youtubeUrl + "&format=json"
            );

            return new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(embededURL)).getString("title");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/DHuckaby/e741f188cdce6ac00d75)

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, I downloaded the jar file and how I'm testing it.

Comment: But how i get the title, whould you please add more code?

Comment: To get the **IOUtils** call to work, I needed this gradle config: `compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'`

Comment: Is the youtubeurl is the full url include http? Or is it only the video id? I just can't make it work.

Comment: same here not getting the json

Comment: Returning null.

Comment: Returning null because of 403. Adding a user agent didnt help either

Comment: Try URL embededURL = new URL("https ..

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Castiblanco
To those who are lazy to find the jars and imports

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm

```
import java.net.URL;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```