# How to get youtube title , description from url

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

Hi I want to get youtube title and description from youtube url to my android application.
I can take only thumbnail...

Comment: POst the JSON that you are getting from youtube API

Comment: Take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766308/get-title-of-youtube-video

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get title of YouTube video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766308/get-title-of-youtube-video)

Answer (score 0):

As your question is a bit broad in scope, not sure as to which "title" you refer to.

However, go [HERE](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/) and you will find what you require.
Plenty of info to get started on.