# Get youtube title fail

Tags: android, youtube-data-api

I want to get Youtube title and others.

I was follow that describe in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44941341/how-to-get-the-title-of-youtube-video-through-the-youtube-api).

here whats i have do:
I use retrofit to request data.

it's my service:

```java
@GET("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=" + C.googlDevApiKey +"&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status")
    Call<JsonObject> getYoutubeInfo(
            @Query("video_id") String videoId
    );
```

it's do the request:

```java
Api.getClient(context)
                .create(Service.class)
                .getYoutubeInfo("v=r2qd_KPQiZE&t=31s")
                .enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()){
                            Log.e("TAG", "youtube Response getYoutubeInfo: " + response.body().toString());
                        } else {
                            Log.e("TAG", "youtube Response getYoutubeInfo: error: " + response.code());
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
```

and the logging interceptor:

```
2019-08-30 07:32:23.679 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp: vary: Origin
2019-08-30 07:32:23.679 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp: vary: X-Origin
2019-08-30 07:32:23.679 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp: content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
2019-08-30 07:32:23.679 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp: date: Fri, 30 Aug 2019 00:32:23 GMT
2019-08-30 07:32:23.679 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp: expires: Fri, 30 Aug 2019 00:32:23 GMT
2019-08-30 07:32:23.679 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp: cache-control: private, max-age=0
2019-08-30 07:32:23.679 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp: x-content-type-options: nosniff
2019-08-30 07:32:23.679 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp: x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
2019-08-30 07:32:23.679 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp: x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
2019-08-30 07:32:23.679 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp: server: GSE
2019-08-30 07:32:23.679 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp: alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43,39"
2019-08-30 07:32:23.680 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp: {
2019-08-30 07:32:23.681 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp:  "error": {
2019-08-30 07:32:23.681 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp:   "errors": [
2019-08-30 07:32:23.681 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp:    {
2019-08-30 07:32:23.681 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp:     "domain": "usageLimits",
2019-08-30 07:32:23.681 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp:     "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
2019-08-30 07:32:23.681 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp:     "message": "The request did not specify any Android package name or signing-certificate fingerprint. Please ensure that the client is sending them or use the API Console to update your key restrictions.",
2019-08-30 07:32:23.681 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp:     "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=XXXXXXX"
2019-08-30 07:32:23.681 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp:    }
2019-08-30 07:32:23.681 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp:   ],
2019-08-30 07:32:23.681 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp:   "code": 403,
2019-08-30 07:32:23.681 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp:   "message": "The request did not specify any Android package name or signing-certificate fingerprint. Please ensure that the client is sending them or use the API Console to update your key restrictions."
2019-08-30 07:32:23.681 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp:  }
2019-08-30 07:32:23.681 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp: }
2019-08-30 07:32:23.681 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (639-byte body)
2019-08-30 07:32:23.681 1683-1760/id.lkmsbwm.bwmmobile.dev D/OkHttp: <-- 403 https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=AIzaSyCd71dtBE9gQhALXOOGo6krGT9F8A7IHJM&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status&video_id=v%3Dr2qd_KPQiZE%26t%3D31s (256ms)
```

I was set Restrict usage to your Android apps, in console.

How to solve it

Answer (score 0):

As per your log your application not register on developer console check first with package name

[follow Youtube doc and then call api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/android)

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;

import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.VideoListResponse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

public class ApiExample {
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRETS= "client_secret.json";
    private static final Collection<String> SCOPES =
        Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly");

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "API code samples";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /**
     * Create an authorized Credential object.
     *
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize(final NetHttpTransport httpTransport) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = ApiExample.class.getResourceAsStream(CLIENT_SECRETS);
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
          GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .build();
        Credential credential =
            new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized API client service.
     *
     * @return an authorized API client service
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
     */
    public static YouTube getService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        final NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Credential credential = authorize(httpTransport);
        return new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
    }

    /**
     * Call function to create API service object. Define and
     * execute API request. Print API response.
     *
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, GoogleJsonResponseException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, GoogleJsonResponseException {
        YouTube youtubeService = getService();
        // Define and execute the API request
        YouTube.Videos.List request = youtubeService.videos()
            .list("snippet,contentDetails,statistics");
        VideoListResponse response = request.setId("Ks-_Mh1QhMc").execute();
        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I check if package name was registered on developer console?

Comment: follow link https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=youtube register api here

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your api is not enabled from google API console. To enable your Youtube v3 API. Try following steps.

Click [this link](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library?project=your_project) and select your project from upper left corner.
Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5nxN.png) for reference image.
Now click on `YouTube Data API v3` and enable the API.
It will look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BteAu.png).

And for your code i guess you are passing the video id here.

```
Api.getClient(context)
            .create(Service.class)
            .getYoutubeInfo("v=r2qd_KPQiZE&t=31s")
            .enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>()
```

so you need to pass only id without any other parameters, then your code will look like

```
Api.getClient(context)
            .create(Service.class)
            .getYoutubeInfo("r2qd_KPQiZE")
            .enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>()
```

Comment: I was sure Youtube Data API v3 enabled,
than change video id without prefix v=, still fail, and showing same error message

Comment: did you double check the key you passing  to your query. Here the things you can try.
[1] try passing OAuth2.0 key to your query, [2] try passing the key you got after enabling youtube v3  API.