# How to get Youtube Video Title in TextView?

Tags: android, textview, youtube-api, title

I have created a list to youtube videos in my app. I have succeeded to fetch Video thumbnail images in ImageView after launching the app. But I do not know how to fetch video titles in TextView. Please help me to fetch videos titles, when I launch the app.

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766308/get-title-of-youtube-video

Comment: how you have list of YouTube videos. Is there any API? Sincerely I don't know.

Comment: I have used API

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<Video>parsingJson(String videoUrl){
    try{
        JSONObject json=parserVideo.getJsonFromYoutube(videoUrl);
        JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(json.getString("items"));
        for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject thumbnail=jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject snippets=thumbnail.getJSONObject("snippet");
            JSONObject defaulturl=snippets.getJSONObject("thumbnails");
            JSONObject url=defaulturl.getJSONObject("high");
            JSONObject resourceId=snippets.getJSONObject("resourceId");
            String videoId=resourceId.getString("videoId");
            String imageurl=url.getString("url");
            String title=snippets.getString("title");
            vObject=new Video(title, imageurl, videoId);
            videoArrayList.add(i,vObject);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return videoArrayList;
}
```

Comment: you have asked only for the title,i thought you must be knowing this

Comment: give properly full answer please.